# Go mod tidy find module but it's not getting to go.sum

Tags: go, command-line-interface, revel

i have a Revel project and i can't start it because everytime i run go mod tidy, it looks like finding module but it's not putting the found module in go.sum

here's my go env

```
GOENV = C:\Users\mycomp\AppData\Roaming\go\env
GOMOD = C:\Program Files\Go\src\myproject\go.mod
GOPATH = C:\Users\micha\go
```

`go version`

```
go version go1.18.3 windows/amd64
```

`revel version`

```
Revel executing: displays the Revel Framework and Go version
Revel Framework :       Unknown (1.1.0 remote master branch)
Revel Cmd       :       1.1.2   (1.1.2 remote master branch)
Revel Modules   :       Unknown (1.1.0 remote master branch)
```

`go mod tidy`

```
go: finding module for package github.com/PaesslerAG/jsonpath
go: finding module for package github.com/tdewolff/test
go: finding module for package github.com/PaesslerAG/gval
go: found github.com/tdewolff/test in github.com/tdewolff/test v1.0.7
go: found github.com/PaesslerAG/gval in github.com/PaesslerAG/gval v1.2.0
go: found github.com/PaesslerAG/jsonpath in github.com/PaesslerAG/jsonpath v0.1.1
```

`go mod init myproject` seem working because it create `go.mod` but it's just odd because it only creates this line, usually it creates a lot of modules i need

```
module myproject

go 1.18
```

then when i type `go mod tidy`, it creates empty `go.sum`. What do i miss ?

Comment: What are you imports? What do you expect in `go.mod`? Are you in the right directory, and why have you set `GOMOD`?

Comment: i expect the dependencies like this `require ( github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery v1.8.0 github.com/cstockton/go-conv v1.0.0 )`.
im in the right directory, the path is `C:\Program Files\Go\src\myproject`.
`GOMOD` is already set by vscode when i clone this repo

Comment: Please create a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cause the problem is too complex to reproduce online, i started to debug and reinstall my Go from scractch, between solving a bug where my program can't run i tried several things that might be useful

1. after Go 1.15 or 1.17 , my Go project can't run properly, so i put it in `C:\Program Files\Go\src\<project_name>`
2. The problem that i have is in `GOPATH` (usually in `C:\Users\<comp_name>\go`) don't have `src` folder, that makes it found downloaded module but can't seem to put it in `go.mod` inside my project

So in the end i reinstall all my Go and Revel. Here's how to delete all your associated Go to really really delete all your files

1. Delete `Go` Folder in `C:\Program Files\Go\`
2. Delete `go` folder in `C:\Users\<comp_name>\go`
3. View all hidden files and delete folder `go-build` in `C:\Users\<comp_name>\AppData\Local`
4. View all hidden files and delete folder `go` if any in `C:\Users\micha\AppData\Roaming`